# Python invert operator - visualizing the negative number

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

In simple words, the definition given for ~n is -n - 1.

For example ~1

```
 1 = 0001
~1 = 1110 (which is -2)
```

For even numbers

say ~2

```
 2 = 0010
~2 = 1101 (which is the representation of -3 in twos complement)
```

But the question is

```
1110 = -2 can be easily visualized as -2 (the right two bits are 10 and the rest all 1)
1101 = -3 can't be visualized like this (going by the above logic it should be -5)
```

So I am wondering is there a simple way to see and tell from twos complement binary what the negative number represents without doing much calculations .

Comment: Do you mean `1110 = -2` and `1101 = -3`?

Comment: Right. 1110 (-2 in twos complement), 1101 (-3 in twos complement)

Comment: You mixed up `~` and `-`.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think he is that stupid...

Comment: Looks like you are looking for [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXAr35BiqK8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~n = -n - 1` is equivalent to `-n = ~n + 1`. That means that to figure out what the negative of a number is, you can invert it (in your head) and add one. Pretend zeros are ones and vice versa, then add one.

Example: Pretend this

```
1101
```

is this

```
0010
```

then add 1

```
0011
```

Thus, `1101` represents `-3`.

Answer (score 0):

The definition comes because of 2's complement representation of integers. So "really" `~n` is `n` with all the bits flipped. But the result of flipping "all" the bits depends in a sense on how many bits `n` has in the first place. CPython uses fixed-width integers internally but the language doesn't present them to the programmer, so the only definition that makes sense *in general* is the arithmetic one `~n = -n - 1`. But the motivation for that definition is flipping the bits of a fixed-width 2's complement integer.

> 1110 = ~2 can be easily visualized as -2

`...1110` is not `~2`, it is `-2`. `~2` is `...1101` because `2` is `...010`.

> 1101 = ~3 can't be visualized like this

`...1101` is not `~3`, it is `-3`. `~3` is `...1100` because `3` is `...011`.

The way I visualize this (when I visualize it at all -- as a mathematician by training I prefer not to consider specific numbers), is to know that in 2's complement, `...10...` is always a negated power of two. So `...10` is -2, `...100` is -4, etc.

Then in order to know what for example `...110110` is, it's `...110000` + `110`, that is to say `-16` + `6`, which is `-10`.

Of course `...110110` is also (by bit flipping) `~1001`, that is to say `~9`, which by the formula is `-9-1`, which is also `-10`. So the system works ;-)